# Getting headers with Python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python requests library to get the header of html pages and use this to get the encoding. But some of the links the requests fails to get header. For such cases I would like to use the encoding "utf-8". How do I handle such cases? How do I handle error returned by requests.head.

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.head(link) #how to handle error in case this fails?
charset = r.encoding
if (not charset):
    charset = "utf-8"
```

Error I am getting when requests fails to get the header :

```
 File "parsexml.py", line 78, in parsefile
  r = requests.head(link)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 74, in head
   return request('head', url, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 40, in request
   return s.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 229, in request
   r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 605, in send
   raise ConnectionError(e)
 requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.standardzilla.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2008/08/01/diaries-of-a-freelancer-day-thirty-seven/
```

Comment: The server you are trying to connect to doesn't respond *at all*; I don't think this has anything to do with your HEAD request, really.

Comment: The domain name `www.standardzilla.com` doesn't exist.

Comment: That's what my question is how do I handle such cases?

Comment: Exception handling; catch the exception and move on. See the posted answer. But that's not really `requests` specific, let alone anything to do with testing for character sets. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your code in a try-except block, catching ConnectionErrors. Like this:

```
try:
    r = requests.head(link) //how to handle error in case this fails?
    charset = r.encoding
    if (not charset):
      charset = "utf-8"
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print 'Unable to access ' + link
```

Comment: @Lanc Great. You can mark the answer as correct if that's the case

Comment: Now I am getting this error now, can you please help me with this.

File "parsexml.py", line 79, in parsefile
    r = requests.head(link,timeout=100,allow_redirects=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 74, in head
    return request('head', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 40, in request
    return s.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 229, in request
    r.send(prefetch=prefetch)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 624, in send
    self._build_response(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 301, in _build_response
    request.send()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 468, in send
    url = self.full_url

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 411, in full_url
    url = requote_uri(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 448, in requote_uri
    return quote(unquote_unreserved(uri), safe="!#$%&'()*+,/:;=?@[]~")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 429, in unquote_unreserved
    c = chr(int(h, 16))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '&e'

Comment: @Lanc it's hard to tell. You've added some more code it looks like.

Comment: @Lanc The result you get back from the call "r = requests.head(link)" is a requests.Response object. It seems from the documentation that you can see the data by calling "print r.text"

Comment: @Lanc Have a look at the documentation here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/

Comment: @Lanc did any of that work? If so, could you mark the issue as fixed

Comment: But how do I do that? Is it by adding a tag "closed"

Comment: There's a tick symbol by my answer. You click on that. Thanks @Lanc.